# How to write a CURL PUT script in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, curl

I have the following code which runs fine if I enter it one line at a time in the terminal:

```
curl -X PUT \
> -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: APPID" \
> -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: APIKEY" \
> -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
> -d '{"production":true}' \
> https://api.parse.com/1/classes/FIELD/OBJECTID
```

How would I turn this into a Ruby script?

I've tried using httparty, uri, net/http, but the syntax of the curl (the \'s and the fact that it's a PUT request) are confusing me.

Comment: Why don't you try using [Curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb), which is the Ruby wrapper for cURL?

Comment: Well, you can just wrap it in `system()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb) is a cURL wrapper. Here's some untested code:

```
require 'curb'

# curl -X PUT \
# > -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: APPID" \
# > -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: APIKEY" \
# > -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
# > -d '{"production":true}' \
# > https://api.parse.com/1/classes/FIELD/OBJECTID

http = Curl.put("https://api.parse.com/1/classes/FIELD/OBJECTID") do |http|
  http.headers['X-Parse-Application-Id'] = 'APPID'
  http.headers['X-Parse-REST-API-Key'] = 'APIKEY'
  http.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
  http.data = '{"production":true}'
end
puts http.body_str
```

Comment: Thanks! Just had to turn http.data into JSON and make it a 2nd argument in the put request, and it works great.